# Get data from json and org.json.JSONException is thrown

Tags: java, php, android, json

Following json will be received but through the `http://localhost/getData.php` but exception is thrown

```
{"username":"not found","password":null}
```

Log I received

```
02-19 17:31:54.745: E/JSON Parser(5277): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
02-19 17:31:59.185: E/JSON Parse(5277): ERROR
```

Following code is the method where exception throw

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url){         

        try{
            String resultText = "";
            EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_box);
            id = edit.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.HttpRequest("http://localhost/getData.php", params);

            resultText = json.getString("username");



        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("JSON Parse","ERROR");
        }

        return "";
    }
```

public class SimpleJsonParser {

```
public SimpleJsonParser(){

}


public JSONObject HttpRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> params){
    InputStream input = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";
    String line;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    paramsString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params,"utf-8");
    url += "?" + paramsString;
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);


    try{


        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            input = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = 
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));


            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                builder.append(line);
            }
            json = builder.toString();

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Parser","Failed to download file");
        }
    }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;
}
```

}

Anything wrong with my code? The code I provided is where exception throws occur

Comment: yes, accessing localhost, which is the android device, not your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside simpleJarsonParser class, I replace the following code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

to

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

and it works. And of course I have replace localhost to 10.0.2.2 as I'm using xampp and android emulator.

Answer (score 2):

From what you mentioned, it appears that you are doing this via an emulator.

Emulator may not be able to access `http://localhost//`. You can try access using, loopback address or the ip address.

Comment: Good point. In the past, I have had too many problems with the Android emulator that I find it is not even worth the stress.

Comment: If you read his code he's getting back a HTTP response, and it's a 200; the problem is it has no content.

Answer (score 2):

You never *verify* that you actually have received anything after reading from the stream returned from the `HttpEntity`. That exception is telling you there's no input at character 0 (The first character) - you have nothing to parse; it's an empty string. Nothing was ever appended to your `StringBuilder`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException
{
    String json = "{\"username\":\"not found\",\"password\":null}";
    JSONObject  jObj = new JSONObject(json);
}
```

Throws no such exception. Often writing a small test case will point you in the right direction.

As others have mentioned, this is probably because you are using the wrong URL or maybe your parameters? Since you're getting back a `200 OK` you're obviously connecting to a webserver and getting a response ...  I'd check to see if that PHP is working as you expect.

Comment: I got 2 wrong in my code, one is what others say my URL is wrong and another one is there is nothing returned from my php file. I think i have to open a new thread asking about my php file.