# Json object is not returned from XAMPP server

Tags: java, php, android, json, parsing

I got a andoird application, I want the result returned to my android textview. I test it on browser and yes the result showed but it return nothing to my android application.

Following code is my php file.

```
<?php

$accounts = mysql_connect("localhost","user123","1234")
or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("user123",$accounts);


if(isset($_GET["id"])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table123 WHERE id = $id");

    if($result != null){
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $user = array();
        $user["username"] = $result["username"];
        $user["password"] = $result["password"];


        echo json_encode($user);
    }else{

    }
}else{

    $user["username"] = "not found";
    $user["password"] = null;
    echo json_encode($user);
}

?>
```

Following code is browser result

```
{"username":"not found","password":null}
```

Even the result is not found, it should return $user show me "not found". It's impossible  nothing is returned to stream. I have test it on my browser and yes it returned $user to me. Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: at localhost, try to put in your PC's IPadress instead.

Comment: I'm using android emulator and i am using ip address 10.0.2.2. I don't think there is anything wrong with my ip address as I have tested on another project

Comment: I would still try that, instead of using localhost. I know there was an error using localhost instead of 10.0.2.2, and don't do you get any logcat error?

Comment: I'm using xampp, so my localhost ip address on my desktop is 127.0.0.1
Here is the doc writting about emulator network [android doc link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

Comment: Are you using Android 3.0 or higher? (what Android version are you using)

Comment: Try using POST instead of GET.

Comment: Bigflow, yes I'm using android 4.2

Comment: Ah, that could be a problem, did you make the httpconnection in the background (Asynch)?

Comment: I did. If you need to take a look at my java code, I got put it on another thread, I have been solving this problem since yesterday and yet, haven't solved it. Here's [the thread I posted yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963993/get-data-from-json-and-org-json-jsonexception-is-thrown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with my PHP source code. I got it work after I replace the following code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

to

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

And everything work.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `"localhost"` with `"10.0.2.2"`

And add this line into your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If you use Android 3.0 or higher (in this case you do).
Then change the emulator to 2.3.3 if possible, then try to run code again.
or
Add these lines into your code:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: @edisonTHK keep the permission line in your file, you must have that too, and I updated answer. This answer could also resolve the problem of your question of yesterday.